# React Native Navigation & Error Boundaries

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm implementing my first react native project & it seems the best way to handle errors is with an app-level Error Boundary. I'm struggling to figure our how to integrate that with `react-native-navigation`. Current code looks like this:

```
# App.js

...

const startApp = () => {
  Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
    screen: {
      screen: 'App.Splash',
      navigatorStyle: {
        navBarHidden: true,
      },
    },
  });
};

export function startTabs() {
  registerScreens(store, Provider);
  sagaMiddleware.run(RootSaga);

  loadIcons().then(() => {
    // Start app only if all icons are loaded
    startApp();
  });
}

startTabs();
```

And the screens.js:

```
# app/Screens.js

...

export default function registerScreens(store, Provider) {
  Navigation.registerComponent('App.Splash', () => SplashContainer, store, Provider);
  ...
 });
```

Because `Navigation.startSingleScreenApp` doesn't return a component, I'm struggling to figure out how to wrap an error boundary either immediately inside or outside the navigator. I tried scouring through react-native-navigation documentation, but couldn't find much help. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, I solved this by wrapping the error boundary inside a parent provider, and passing that to each navigator screen. Eg:

```
// ProviderWithErrorBoundary.js

const ProviderWithErrorBoundary = ({ store, children }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        {children}
      </ErrorBoundary>
  </Provider>
);
```

Then passed then into my `Screens.js` via

```
// Screens.js
export default function RegisterScreens(store, Provider) {
  Navigation.registerComponent('App.Home', () => HomeContainer, store, Provider);
})
```

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: Nice one as well! I didn't thought you can redefine `Provider`. Only one small limitation that I see: all screens must be wrapped with this custom `Provider` even if they don't benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

What I did when I had such requirement, I displayed `Root` HOC component, that wraps first screen, instead of actual first screen. Then you can handle errors inside `Root`, because it will be always loaded and use `this.props.navigator` of `Root` component to display errors, for example, with `showModal()`.

Another benefit of having `Root` component that you can switch displayed root screen from side menu very easily naturally, without any special handling navigation actions. Or you can implement splash->login->home flow, like I did in the example below.

It can look like that:

```js
class Root: Component {
  static propTypes = {
    navigator: PropTypes.instanceOf(Navigator).isRequired;
  }

  constructor(props) {
    this.state = { 
      content: <Splash navigator={this.props.navigator} onLoadComplete={this.handleLoadComplete} />,
    };
    // Adding network interceptor with handleNetworkError() as callback
  }
  
  handleLoadComplete = () => {
    this.setState({
      content: <Login navigator={this.props.navigator} onLoginComplete={this.handleLoginComplete} />,
    });
  }
  
  handleLoginComplete = () => {
    this.setState({ 
      content: <Home navigator={this.props.navigator} />,
    });
  }
  
  handleNetworkError = (error) => {
    this.props.navigator.showModal(screens.NetworkError, {
      passProps: { error },
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return this.content;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wrapping each screen individually with my ErrorBoundary component. Not the most elegant or scalable option, perhaps, but it was quick, dirty, and easy, and for my use case it made the most sense.